# Magento 2 Products arent showing in Catagory

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I have uploaded my products, but the products are not visible in the categories I added while they appear with the search url. I checked the configurations everyting seems right. My products were entered as out of stock. I will add an image below as an example

[image]

In the picture you see, 84 products are available in categories. But when I go to the category, no results appear. Like this;

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Log in to your Magento admin panel.

> Navigate to Stores > Configuration.

> Click on "Catalog" in the left-hand menu, then click on "Inventory".

> In the "Stock Options" section, find the "Display Out of Stock
> Products" option and set it to "Yes".

> Click on "Save Config" to apply the new setting.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I did but it is still not working

Comment: Try after clearing the cache.

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: Harun I tried already like that. I am using 2.4.6 magento version. Should I change?

Comment: No, that's not the correct solution.

Comment: Double-check that the stock status of your out-of-stock products is set correctly.

Comment: To do this, go to Catalog > Products in your Magento admin panel, select an out-of-stock product, and check that the "Qty" and "Stock Status" fields are set to zero and "Out of Stock", respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Could you please take a look at the last picture I added to the question? All my products have been uploaded to the system in this way. I think this error because of some stock problem.

Comment: possible reasons; check qty, cheek in advance inventory is selected in stock?, try indexer, cache flush.